# Double-slit experiment with electron waves and the resulting interference pattern

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Let's consider a setup where I have two slits separated by distance $a$. Let's say initially, the electron wave passes through the two slits undisturbed and then form an interference pattern. I assume that just as is the case in the classical double-slit experiment, the central bright peak is symmetrically at the center of the observing screen.

Let's say now I have an Aharonv-Bohm setup with a long solenoid that with field B perpendicular to the plane of propagation of the wave.

My question is: Let's say I want to find the shift in the location of the central bright spot once the setup is introduced. The first thing that comes to my mind is to find the relative phase shift, let's call it $\Delta \phi$. Most of the textbooks even go on to find it exactly. How do I use this to find the distance by which the bright spot on the screen is shifted if I know $\Delta \phi$?

Attempt:
So I guess all we need to do is use $\Delta \phi$ to find additional path length travelled by the waves, and then use trigonometric relations to figure out the new central bright spot. Am I on the right track?

Edit: After some more consideration, I have further confusions. Let's say initially if the $B = 0$, then the phase difference between the two waves is denoted by $\delta(B=0)$. For the central bright spot, $\delta(B=0) =0$.However, once $B$ field is non-zero inside the solenoid, the total relative phase-difference is:
$\Delta \phi = \delta(B=0) + \delta_1$. The problem though is now that the central bright spot has shifted, I think that the $\delta(B=0)$ need not be equal to $0$.

Comment: Yes. You are on the right track.

Comment: Thank you. It would be a bit helpful if you could give me a little hint on how to proceed from here. @SuperfastJellyfish